# Missing Apache 2.4 error.log

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, virtualhost, log-files

Ubuntu 16.04
Apache 2.4

I have several virtual hosts defined. Every one defines an own error.log:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.xyz.de.80.error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.xyz.de.80.access.log combined
```

In `/etc/apache2/envvars`, I changed the `APACHE_LOG_DIR`:

```
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/mnt/logs/reverseProxy1$SUFFIX
```

In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, I set the log level and `ErrorLog`:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel debug
```

So I have in my Apache log dir all virtual hosts access and error log files.
In `/var/log/apache2`, I have several module specific log files and the common apache2 `access.log`.
But I can't find the common apache2 `error.log`.
I am aware that virtual host specific errors will be logged in the specific log files, but I expected to see apache2 core debugging information in an `error.log` file.

What configuration do I miss for apache2 to create a common `error.log`?

Comment: Enable `mod_info` and browse to http://server/server-info to see where the running process thinks it's writing to; the above directive might be being overridden somewhere else.  Then check the permissions on the folder and file indicated to make sure the user can write to it.

Comment: From the server Info: `Server Built With: -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"` `Module core.c: 128: ErrorLog /mnt/apache_logs/reverseProxy1/error.log`

Comment: and `In file: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf  3: ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log` so this seems the reason, your assumption was right. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: side note: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html#security

Comment: Thanks, it's restricted to my workstation, and now i have disabled mod_info. @SmallClanger Please create an answer so i can mark the answer as correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enabling `mod_info` and browsing to http://server/server-info to see where the running process thinks it's writing to; the above directive was being overridden somewhere else:

```
Server Built With: -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log" Module core.c: 128: ErrorLog /mnt/apache_logs/reverseProxy1/error.log
```